# Adding Application.Property file

Tags: commercetools

Task :bootRun FAILED
15:40:41,991 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource please help me to solve this issue

15:40:41,992 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
15:40:41,992 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/D:/Commercetools_SDK2/commercetools-sdk-v2/examples/spring/build/resources/main/logback.xml]
15:40:42,098 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
15:40:42,099 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
15:40:42,103 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [Console]
15:40:42,181 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[Console] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
15:40:42,181 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[Console] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
15:40:42,181 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[Console] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
15:40:42,182 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.thymeleaf] to DEBUG
15:40:42,182 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [commercetools] to DEBUG
15:40:42,182 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
15:40:42,182 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [Console] to Logger[ROOT]
15:40:42,183 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
15:40:42,183 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@2f0a87b3 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

2023-11-02 15:40:42,361 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser: requestId= Properties location [classpath:application.properties] not resolvable: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2023-11-02 15:40:43,056 WARN  [main] org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: requestId= Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ctpSecurityConfig.CtpReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver' defined in file [D:\Commercetools_SDK2\commercetools-sdk-v2\examples\spring\build\classes\java\main\com\commercetools\sdk\examples\spring\config\CtpSecurityConfig$CtpReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ctpClientBeanService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ctp.client.id' in value "${ctp.client.id}"
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ctpSecurityConfig.CtpReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver' defined in file [D:\Commercetools_SDK2\commercetools-sdk-v2\examples\spring\build\classes\java\main\com\commercetools\sdk\examples\spring\config\CtpSecurityConfig$CtpReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ctpClientBeanService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ctp.client.id' in value "${ctp.client.id}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
at com.commercetools.sdk.examples.spring.Application.main(Application.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ctpClientBeanService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ctp.client.id' in value "${ctp.client.id}"
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ctp.client.id' in value "${ctp.client.id}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180)
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:936)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
... 35 more

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

added application.property file with client_id and other requirements. but it is showing nothing is added

Comment: Did you tried to include the credentials in application.properties file in the resources folder https://github.com/commercetools/commercetools-sdk-java-v2/blob/main/examples/spring/src/main/resources/application.properties The error message says it can't find the file on the class path. Another option would be to use environment variables.